# Password Hash Mismatch Issue in WPF Application with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, hash

I'm encountering an issue with `password` validation in my WPF application using Entity Framework for data access. The problem arises when comparing the hashed `password` generated during login with the stored hash in the database.

Details:

Database: SQL Server
Entity Framework: (6.0)
Password Storage: Hashed using SHA256 with a salt
Database Column for Password Hash: nvarchar(200)
Issue Summary:

When attempting to log in, the hashed `password` generated during login does not match the stored hash in the database.
The data type of the `PasswordHash` column is nvarchar(200), and case sensitivity is not the issue.
The `GenerateHashPassword` method is used consistently for hashing during login and during initial password storage.

```cs
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
using (var dbContext = new DbProjectEntities())
            {
                var loginService = new LoginService(dbContext);

                // Replace "bbb" and "000" with actual values from user input
                bool isLoginSuccessful = loginService.ValidateLogin("mmm", "000");
                if (isLoginSuccessful)
                {
                    // Login successful logic
                    Console.WriteLine("Login Successful!");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Login unsuccessful logic
                    Console.WriteLine("Login Unsuccessful!");
                }
            }
}

 public bool ValidateLogin(string username, string providedPassword)
        {
            // Retrieve user by username
            var user = dbContext.UserCredentials.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                // Output stored password hash from the database
                Console.WriteLine($"Stored PasswordHash from Database: {user.PasswordHash}");

                // Combine provided password with stored salt
                string combinedPassword = providedPassword + user.Salt;

                // Output combined password for debugging
                Console.WriteLine($"Combined Password: {combinedPassword}");

                // Hash the combined password
                string hashedPassword = PasswordBoxHelper.GenerateHashPassword(combinedPassword, user.Salt);

                // Output generated hash for debugging
                Console.WriteLine($"Generated Hash: {hashedPassword}");

                // Compare the generated hash with the stored password hash
                bool isPasswordMatch = hashedPassword == user.PasswordHash;

                Console.WriteLine($"Password Match: {isPasswordMatch}");

                return isPasswordMatch;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("User not found.");
            return false; // User not found
        }
    }
```

and this is GenerateHashPassword

```cs
 public static string GenerateHashPassword(string password, string salt)
        {
            using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), 10000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
            {
                byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(256 / 8); // 256 bits
                return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            }
        }
```

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Checked the data type and case sensitivity of the PasswordHash column.
Verified the consistency of the hashing algorithm and parameters.
Tested hashing independently to compare with stored hash.
Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance on identifying the root cause of the mismatch and suggestions for resolving the issue. Any insights or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only logical conclusion is that there's something different between the way you're generating the initial password hash and how you're generating the hash for comparison. You haven't shown us the code for the initial generation though, so we can't possibly know what that difference would be. My guess would be that it has something to do with the salt but we shouldn't need to guess.

Comment: i just add the initial code of execute. and no more.

Comment: There's no code there that is using that `GenerateHashPassword` to create the initial hash at registration so you clearly haven't provided all the relevant code. We need to be able to execute both code snippets to see whether they generate the same value and, if not, what the difference is between them. We can't do that if we've only seen one of them.

Comment: A good implementation stores the salt, used hash algorithm and iterations (the complete recipe to build the hashed password) inside the hashed password and extract it from there to verify the given password like [BCrypt.Net](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net) does

Comment: Another example is [PasswordHasher](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b89e21ed72c7afd58fd372f7b8e6299847a8153a/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L141) from ASP.NET Core

Comment: Updated. hope it has more meaning.